# Ignoring exception in command None: nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "mute" is not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, nextcord

Я новичок в программировании и решил написать дискорд бота на библиотеке Nextcord. Но столкнулся с проблемой: создал команду mute, но когда прописываешь команду в чат, бот выдает ошибку:

> Ignoring exception in command None:
> nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "mute" is not found

Проверял код, ошибок нет.

Вот и сам код:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands


class Mute(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def mute(self, ctx, member=nextcord.Member):        
        role = nextcord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="MUTED")
        guild = ctx.guild
        if role not in guild.roles:
            perms = nextcord.Permissions(send_messages=False, speak=False)
            await guild.create_role(name="MUTED", permissions=perms)
            await member.add_roles(role)

            conf_embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Успешно замьючен!")
            conf_embed.add_field(name="Кем замьючен:", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}", inline=False)
            conf_embed.add_field(name="Был замьючен:", value=f"{member.mention}", inline=False)

            await ctx.send(embed=conf_embed)
        else:
            await member.add_roles(role)

            conf_embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Успешно замьючен!")
            conf_embed.add_field(name="Кем замьючен:", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}", inline=False)
            conf_embed.add_field(name="Был замьючен:", value=f"{member.mention}", inline=False)

            await ctx.send(embed=conf_embed)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Mute(bot))
```

Заранее спасибо!